# convert python localtime to java

Tags: java, python

I am converting python to java but I do not know python (I know java).

Here is the python:

```
localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
```

and it is being used in this way:

```
policyname = 'LLC-Uninstall-D%s%s%s-T%s%s%s%s' % (localtime[0], localtime[1], localtime[2], localtime[3], localtime[4], localtime[5], localtime[6])
```

I would like to do the same thing in Java. Is this possible?

Comment: localtime returns a timestruct (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time)


I am sure java also has a localtime function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("'LLC-Uninstall-D'yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
String formatted = df.format(new Date());
```

The documentation for the formatting symbols can be [found at the JavaDoc Page for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you can use that to configure the exact string produced to meet your needs.